# How to add arrow next to y-axis of heatmap to mark specific gene of interest in R?

Tags: r, expression, heatmap

I know how to create a heat map but I want to add an arrow next to my gene of interest on the specific row. I saw some heat maps that have the arrows but I couldn't find the solution.
Here is my code for the heat map with heatmap.3 :

```
heatmap.3(as.matrix(exprs(df)),keysize = 1, Colv=T,Rowv=F,main = "My heatmap", 
 ColSideColors=Col.matrix,side.height.fraction=0.5,col=my.colors, 
  dendrogram="column", scale="none",  breaks=my.breaks, key=TRUE)
```

Here is an example of how to draw a heat map with heatmap.3 package.

```
  ## load library
  require("GMD")
  require(cluster)
  ## load data
  data(ruspini)
  ## heatmap on a `dist' object
  x <- gdist(ruspini)
  main <- "Heatmap of Ruspini data"
  dev.new(width=10,height=10)
  heatmap.3(x, main=main) # with a title and a map in square!
```

and here is the link to another heat map to visualise what I am looking for, adding an arrow next to the heat map. If you look at the heat map you could find two arrows next to the y-axis of the heat map.

It's in this article:
Veillonella, Firmicutes: [Microbes disguised as Gram negatives](http://standardsingenomics.org/index.php/sigen/article/viewFile/298/1064/9070), doi:10.4056/sigs.2981345